# using glDrawElements with texture co-ordinates

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am a beginner with open GL ES 2.0 on android c/c++ (NDK) and can draw a cube using glDrawElements call with proper indices passed.

However I wanted to know how does you pass texture co-ordinates when drawing with glDrawElements since you are using indices will the indices apply to the textureCordinate array too?

or do you need to put repetitive data in the texture Coordinate array in the order as defined in indices array for each vertex (making no of texCords in array = no of indices)?

Or is there a similar way to define indices for texture cordinates in the texCordinates Array?

Comment: There are a lot of (near) duplicates of this. A search of "opengl texture coordinates index" on this site shows a bunch of very similar question just on the first page.

Comment: Oh snap! Bloody hell how did I missed that idea! Verdammt